# Problema css html height 100% no permite hacer scroll al imprimir en app angular SPA

Tags: html, css, angular, print, spa

hola tengo el siguiente problema:
yo tengo el siguiente codigo en mi styles.scss

```
html,body {height: 100%;}
```

El cual hacer que mi app se expanda por toda la pantalla y funciona correctamente
[image: imagen demostrativa del codifgo anterior funcionando]

el detalle viene cuando quiero hacer la impresion de algo que estoy viendo en pantalla Pero la pagina es scroolable, lo que pasa es que solo me permite imprimir lo que esta actualmente en pantalla y un poco mas de eso pero no la pagina completa.

[image: imagen de problema de impresion]

En la imagen anterior el horario va de 7am a 7pm y como se logra observar apenas llega a las 12m, el problema es causado por el codigo en css `html, { height: 100%; }`
si yo lo remuevo la impresion del navegador funciona correctamente


[image: impresion del navegador funcionando]


 Pero al visualizar las paginas con poco contenido este se ve reducido a una pequeña parte de la pantalla

[image: prblema al remover el codigo css]
`
alguien sabe que puedo hacer para que ambos comportamientos. tanto como la impresion y el expandir el html al tamaño de la pantalla funcionen??

Comment: puedes usar los media query y que unos estilos apliquen únicamente para print y otros para screen `@media print {  /*estilos*/ }`

Comment: Gracias por responder amigo exactamente eso estoy implementando para quitar algunos elementos innecesarios pero no se como hacer para remover el elemento height del css desde el media query es decir, se como modificar el tamaño del mismo pero no como removerlo que sería lo mismo a no tener ese atributo

Comment: intenta poniendo un valor height: auto;

Comment: `unset` o `inherit` también pueden ir

Comment: muchas gracias por comentar amigos efectivamenete con uso de "unset" se soluciono mi problema 
@media print {
  html {
    height: unset;
  }
mi codigo resultante
cabe aclarar que con "auto"  tambien tambien se soluciona el problema, muchas gracias amigos por compartir su conocimiento

Answer (score 0):

lo que yo veo es que debes aplicar un estilo llamado `overflow-y: auto` o un `overflow-y: scroll` para obligar que en el elemento de la impresión aparezca un scroll que puedas utilizar, igual aquí te dejo un link de w3school para que mires las propiedades que mejor se adapten a tu proyecto : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Buen aporte, igual yo potaría por fuentes con mejor recibimiento en la comunidad como: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y

Comment: también, es muy buena

Comment: muchas gracias amigos, revisare lo que me comentan pues quiza me gustaria mejorar mi codigo, de momento lo solucione con poner el soguiente codigo @media print {
  html {
    height: unset;
  }
que es el codigo que comentaba nuestro amigo Alo Malbarez

Comment: vale amigo sí tienes otra duda nos comentas

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta al problema fue al siguiente

```css
@media print {
  html {
    height: unset;
  }
```

El valor `height` puede variar a `auto` y sigue funcionando correctamente
muchas gracias a los compañeros que respondieron